# $http post method response "OK" but after the response nothing has been updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http

I want to post some JSON in to the URL in the Following.Though the response become success there are no updations in the web. What can be the reason for it? How to fix this?

```
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         dataType: "json",
         async: true,
         data: JSON.stringify(dataaa),
         url: dataElementURL,
         headers: {
             "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(  instance.uname + ':' + instance.pword ),
             'Accept': 'application/json',
             'Content-type': 'application/json'
         },
         success: function (response) {
             console.log('OrgUnit Import response: '+response.status)
         },
         error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             console.log(textStatus);
             console.log(errorThrown);
             console.log(request);
         }
     });
```

Comment: Where are you updating things ?

Comment: `success: function (response) {
             console.log('OrgUnit Import response: '+response.status)
         },` the handler just prints to console

Comment: but stringfy data should be posted to the url which i have mentioned. right?